# Adding a header after images in an imagecontainer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 images in a row with some text overlaid over the images. I want a new header below these images with the usual space above the header (between the images and the header). I have tried adding a new row as well as a div to the title to give it padding but it seems that the title wants to stay aligned with the images above it.

Created a jfiddle here to illustrate the issue I'm having with the "2nd title" that needs to have space above it between it and the pictures.
https://jsfiddle.net/wb7t5718/1/

here is code

```css
.imagecontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  /* important */
  position: relative;
  /* important(so we can absolutely position the   description div */
  padding-right: 12px;
}
.description {
  position: absolute;
  /* absolute position (so we can position it where we want)*/
  bottom: 0px;
  /* position will be on bottom */
  left: 0px;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'tahoma';
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
  /* transparency */
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  /* IE transparency */
}
.description a {
  color: white;
}
p.description_content {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h3>First title</h3>
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/220x200" height="200" width="220" />
  <div class='description'>
    <p class='description_content'><a href="#">text</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/220x200" height="200" width="220" />
  <div class='description'>
    <p class='description_content'><a href="#">text</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/220x200" height="200" width="220" />
  <div class='description'>
    <p class='description_content'><a href="#">text</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <h3>Second title needs to be below pictures with space above it</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want, but I think you wont to like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wb7t5718/2/

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the "br" above description class.

```
<h3>First title</h3>
       <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x200" height="200" width="220" />
     <br><br><br><br>
    <div class='description'>
    <p class='description_content'><a href="#">text</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/220x200" height="200" width="220" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div class='description'>
    <p class='description_content'><a href="#">text</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x200" height="200" width="220" />
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div class='description'>
    <p class='description_content'><a href="#">text</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
<h3>Second title needs to be below pictures with space above it</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndyB please try this out and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `float: left;` to `.imagecontainer` and try..

Answer (score 0):

Just add `clear:both` to `.row` class to clear floating of div. and add margin/padding top to getting spacing on top.

```
.row{
  clear:both;
  padding-top:5px;
}
```